# .NET Core API view model return

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to run a query that returns only select fields off of my model and related entities.  I get an error:

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
    Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type
 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: int TeamId, string Name>>' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ApplicationCore.Entities.TeamViewModel>>'    AppName C:....\Controllers\TeamController.cs    64  Active
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
  [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<TeamViewModel>>> List(int id)
    {
        var team = await _context.Teams
            .Where(c => c.TeamId == id)
            .Select(c => new
            {
                c.TeamId,
                c.Team.Name
            })
            .ToListAsync();

        if (team == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return team;
    }


class TeamViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string TeamName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are selecting an *anonymous type* and trying to return it as a concrete `TeamViewModel` type.

Assuming `TeamViewModel` was the intended type and that it is defined with the properties attempted in the original question, the action should be refactored..

```
[HttpGet("{id:int}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<TeamViewModel>>> List(int id) {
    var team = await _context.Teams
        .Where(c => c.TeamId == id)
        .Select(c => new TeamViewModel { //<--
            TeamId = c.TeamId,
            TeamName = c.Team.Name
        })
        .ToListAsync();

    if (team.Count == 0) {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return team;
}
```

Note your query wont return *null* so no need to check for that.

If the list is empty then that should indicate that there are no records.

Comment: Thanks! That addressed my issue and I'm able to get the data I wanted, however, I'm also getting all the fields from my Teams entity.  Shouldn't the fact that my select only includes TeamId and TeamName mean I only get those fields back?

Comment: You will get back everything from the context, but the projection is only accessing two properties. You determine how much is sent back from the controller action. That is why it is usually advised to create the view model and not send the entity.

Comment: I see.  That is what I was trying to do by creating a projection on the viewmodel.  I'll play with it.